# Override notification templates and put them on classpath

Tags: alfresco

We need to customize for example the standard mail invitation template by changing the text a bit. I know this can be done by editing the freemarker template for the invitation that is stored in the data dictionary. This is however not optimal when it comes to application packaging. Is it somehow possible to extend the templates in the manner that they could be put on the extension classpath like the regular extension mechanism?

edit:
Found out that the inviation template for emails are hardcoded in the InviteSender java-class. :(

So I guess we will have to extend that class (and a lot of others) to do this.

Another solution I can think of would be to write a patch that replaces the ftl-files in the data dictionary with our edited ones at install time. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been done and has been written in this [blog](http://blog.abstractive.ca/2012/06/alfresco-process-template-on-classpath/).

In short **No** there is no out of the box solution for it.
Yes you could bootstrap your files and Patch Alfresco's (that's the most common used way).

You should also consider the fact that changing a template without to have access to the server where Alfresco is installed is a nice feature. With this functional guys who manage/operate/use Alfresco can change templates to their needs.

Comment: Yeah I use the way described in the blog when I made a template of my own. Now since I need to modify existing templates I will write at patch that replaces the existing content with my new version. Wil need to montitor though that on upgrades Alfresco don't replace them with new versions as well in the future...

Comment: Yes but that's a common upgrade process. Do a diff on the changes you've made vs Alfresco's own. And change your template.

Comment: Yes, but thats something we always try to avoid as long as possible isn't it :)